# How i removed blank space in html page while printing?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a page where I print this page content. My problem is when the page is load a print dialogue box appears and there is empty white space at the bottom. How do I remove this blank space? I tried to give `min-height:100vh` to body but it is not working [image: screenshot]. Please also check print css

```css
@page {
     /* size: auto;  auto is the initial value */
    margin: 3.5mm;
  }
 @media print{ 
table { page-break-inside:auto; }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }
    thead { display:table-header-group; }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change and check the following style values based on your content length & width.

```
@page { size: 100mm 50mm } /* output size */
body.receipt .sheet { width: 58mm; height: 50mm } /* sheet size */
@media print { body.receipt { width: 58mm } } /* fix for Chrome */
```